# Spring boot app with web.xml in the .war file

Tags: spring

I have a spring boot application that works fine in tomcat embedded. But when i take the .war file as the final output I have no WEB-INF/web.xml file. To deploy this in a PASS i need the web.xml in the final output .war. How can i get it in the built?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you deploy it in a Servlet 3.0 compatible container, you don't need a web.xml. You can also use the WebApplicationInitializer mechanism from Spring (check for example the SpringBootServletInitializer).

Comment: but if i don't inherit the spring-boot-samples parent(in example), i can't create war correctly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35885898/how-to-create-war-file-in-spring-boot-without-parent-and-with-web-xml